# Nested decltype with msvc result in error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, visual-c++, function-pointers

I'm trying to make a class that hold a member function as a constexpr static member. Things are working great on GCC and Clang, but on MSVC 2015, things get more complicated.

Here a code reproducing the error:

```
template<typename T, T t>
struct Method {
    using Type = T;
    constexpr const static T method = t;
};

template<typename T, T t>
constexpr const T Method<T, t>::method;

struct Test1 {
    void method1(int, double) {}
};

struct Test2 {
    template<typename T, T t, typename... Params>
    void method2(Params...) {}

    template<typename T, T t>
    void method3(int, double) {}

    //using p1_t = Method<
    //  decltype(&Test2::method2<decltype(&Test1::method1), &Test1::method1, int, double>),
    //  &Test2::method2<decltype(&Test1::method1), &Test1::method1, int, double>
    //>;
};

int main()
{
    Method<
        void (Test2::*)(int, double),
        &Test2::method2<decltype(&Test1::method1), &Test1::method1, int, double>
    > p1;

    //Method<
    //  decltype(&Test2::method2<decltype(&Test1::method1), &Test1::method1, int, double>),
    //  &Test2::method2<decltype(&Test1::method1), &Test1::method1, int, double>
    //> p2;

    Method<
        void (Test2::*)(int, double),
        &Test2::method3<decltype(&Test1::method1), &Test1::method1>
    > p3;

    //Method<
    //  decltype(&Test2::method3<decltype(&Test1::method1), &Test1::method1>),
    //  &Test2::method3<decltype(&Test1::method1), &Test1::method1>
    //> p4;

    return 0;
}
```

Uncommenting the declaration of `p2` and `p4` result in a error on MSVC 2015.

But on GCC, everything's okay, [live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b2fb9d0ee8f68ef)

Is it possible to do somthing like this on MSVC and what are the workaround?

Comment: This looks a bug of VC. By adding meaningless function call, the code might compile like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/832d2d9f5ea71525).

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Aww snap! It seems to work when declaring a variable but not  in a typedef or using declaration.

Comment: Glad it helped :-) Possibly are there still issues?

Comment: I discovered some other bugs related to where the using declaration is made, I think I'm really close now, I'll tell you what I discovered soon

Comment: It seem it doesn't like accessing a parent's class protected member in decltype through the name of the current class,  which is the only way to do it according to the standart. Accessing the member directly with the name of the parent seems to work, even if it's not standard.

Comment: That scares me :-S My current compiler is VC2013. There are many bugs in VC2013, but VC2015 seems to have equally many bugs...

Comment: Sure, there are still errors, but there's over 750 [bug fixed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/07/01/c-compiler-front-end-fixes-in-vs2015.aspx)